# How to LEFT JOIN WITH ORDER BY COLUMN IN RIGHT TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, sql-order-by

```
    SELECT S.ID_SUPPLIER, S.NAMA_PERUSAHAAN, S.NAMA_CP, S.EMAIL,
        P.ID_PROVINSI, P.NAMA_PROVINSI, K.ID_KK, K.NAMA_KK,
        GROUP_CONCAT(B.NAMA_BAHAN_BAKU) as NAMA_BAHAN_BAKU
    FROM M_SUPPLIER S
    LEFT JOIN M_PROVINSI P ON S.ID_PROVINSI = P.ID_PROVINSI
    LEFT JOIN M_KOTA_KABUPATEN K ON S.ID_KK = K.ID_KK
    LEFT JOIN SUPPLIER_BAHAN_BAKU SUP ON S.ID_SUPPLIER = SUP.ID_SUPPLIER
    LEFT JOIN M_BAHAN_BAKU B on B.ID_BAHAN_BAKU = SUP.ID_BAHAN_BAKU
    GROUP BY S.ID_SUPPLIER
    ORDER BY B.NAMA_BAHAN_BAKU ASC
```

[image: This is what happen now]

What I want is the column NAMA_BAHAN_BAKU is asc
like this..

```
ID_SUPPLIER |...| NAMA_BAHAN_BAKU
SU0002 |....|
Pewarna Makanan Egg Yellow,Pewarna Makanan Orange Red
```

(THIS IS WHAT I WANT. I WANT IT TO BE ASCENDING)

```
SU0001 |....|
Baking Powder, Garam, Gula, MSG, Telur, Tepung Tapioka
```

(THIS IS WHAT I WANT. I WANT IT TO BE ASCENDING)

Comment: Note that you should really be grouping by ALL the non-aggregated columns in your select.

Comment: @Strawberry The SQL standard does give rules for when FDs allow non-aggregate select of non-grouped columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ordering inside the `group_concat`, and then, in the global `ORDER BY`, take off the `b.`, you are using an alias:

```
SELECT S.ID_SUPPLIER, S.NAMA_PERUSAHAAN, S.NAMA_CP, S.EMAIL, P.ID_PROVINSI, P.NAMA_PROVINSI, K.ID_KK, K.NAMA_KK, GROUP_CONCAT(B.NAMA_BAHAN_BAKU ORDER BY B.NAMA_BAHAN_BAKU ASC) as NAMA_BAHAN_BAKU
FROM M_SUPPLIER S
LEFT JOIN M_PROVINSI P ON S.ID_PROVINSI = P.ID_PROVINSI
LEFT JOIN M_KOTA_KABUPATEN K ON S.ID_KK = K.ID_KK
LEFT JOIN SUPPLIER_BAHAN_BAKU SUP ON S.ID_SUPPLIER = SUP.ID_SUPPLIER
LEFT JOIN M_BAHAN_BAKU B on B.ID_BAHAN_BAKU = SUP.ID_BAHAN_BAKU
GROUP BY S.ID_SUPPLIER
ORDER BY NAMA_BAHAN_BAKU ASC
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works!!!  ^^
So the key is GROUP_CONCAT(B.NAMA_BAHAN_BAKU ORDER BY B.NAMA_BAHAN_BAKU ASC) as NAMA_BAHAN_BAKU
Its still work even without the last sentence
ORDER BY NAMA_BAHAN_BAKU ASC